# React Native: Why Mobile App is not changed when cache is changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, expo

I use React native.

When I use web with `react`, if I change cache info then that change is automatically applied on my web screen.

But in case of `react native` app, if I change cache info(I check cache is correctly changed), my mobile app (`expo`) doesn't change at all. So I need to refresh my screen once again.

Is that correct? or did I do something wrong?

For example, on react when I run this function to edit cache.
It is written to when I click button, this function runs.
It delete my comment from server then delete this record from cache.

When I run it on web, this deleted comment disappears automatically on web.
But on my app, it has no change at all.

```
  const updateDeleteComment = (cache, result) => {
    const {
      data: {
        deleteComment: { ok, error },
      },
    } = result;
    if (ok) {
      cache.evict({ id: `Comment:${id}` });
      cache.modify({
        id: `Photo:${photoId}`,
        fields: {
          commentNumber(prev) {
            return prev - 1;
          },
        },
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please add some snippet (What you have tried in terms of code)

Comment: I add more info :)